# question when using interpolate for missing value

Tags: python, pandas

I had a dataset looks like below:

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': ['2018-01-03 00:00:00', '2018-01-04 00:00:00', '2018-01-05 00:00:00'],
    'coal': [2669.0, np.nan ,2731.0],
     'hydro': [222.0, np.nan ,230.0],
    'unit': ['Gwh', 'Gwh', 'Gwh'],
})

test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date'])
```

and when i was trying to fill the null by using interpolate method:

```
for x in test.columns.to_list():
    test[x] = test[x].interpolate())
```

it got error :

```
Invalid fill method. Expecting pad (ffill) or backfill (bfill). Got linear
```

and when i remove the

```
test['date'] = pd.to_datetime(test['date'])
```

it will work just fine, so i dont know why this happened:(

and also, it works fine when i using the sample df, but when i try it on my own dataset, it has no error, but the null value still exist, like the fillna() never used:(

and when i was using below code, then use the fillna code:

```
test['date'] = test['date'].astype(object)
```

it works on my sample, but not my own dataset:( my own dataset still like i never used the fillna method

im so confused by now:( was wondering if someone could explain why this happened?
I try to google it, but no result:(

or maybe i dont know how to google it:(

P.S.
it works fine if i fill it one column at a time when i try it on my own dataset, like:

```
test['coal'] = test['coal'].interpolate())
test['hydro'] = test['hydro'].interpolate())
```

but not the for loops:(

Its working when i first change the dtype to float, so maybe something wrong when it was object(not all object)?

```
for x in total_list:
    df_all[x] = df_all[x].astype(float)
    df_all[x] = df_all[x].interpolate()
```

anyway, thank you all:) this took me 2hours already:(

Comment: so weired, i added "hi guys" in the begining of my question, but it got automatically removed:/

Comment: You don't need to use `fillna`.

Comment: @rpanai wow! thank you:) but it still has the sample problem:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to interpolate the given columns

```py
cols_to_interpolate = ["coal", "hydro"]
test[cols_to_interpolate] = test[cols_to_interpolate].interpolate()
```